# Can't deploy Grails War file in tomcat - results in 404

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, tomcat7, war

I have a `GrailsApplication.war` file with me, and i added that into the `webapps` folder (tomcat 7). 
When i tried to access the url (`<ipaddress>:8080/GrailsApplication`) it gives me a 404 error. What have i done wrong deploying the grails war file ?

Grails version : 2.2.4

Tomcat : 7

Server : Ubuntu

Comment: Is `grails.serverURL` set accordingly in `Config.groovy` for production env?

Comment: What do you mean? sorry i am a beginner

Comment: Ok, added as an answer as that was too much for a comment. :)

Comment: Give me a second. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Grails 2 apps, there should be a config setting present in `Config.groovy` as below, verify if that is present:

```
environments {
    production {
        grails.serverURL = "http://<youripaddress>:8080/${appName}"
    }
}
```

Comment: It still gives as 404. the WAR file created was `GrailsApplication_1.0.war` and i dropped it in the `webapp` folder.

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior as well. This answer ultimately has not solved my issue. i'm using Grails 3.1.10.  Run-app runs great.. deploy a war doesn't error in any way. Cannot get past 404.

Comment: @Kirby Answer is not applicable for Grails 3.*. It is only applicable for Grails 2.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can also post an elaborated question in SO which will help get more attention and ultimately an answer for you.

Comment: My SO is here. Thank you for your replies. :)     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752633/404-when-deploying-grails-3-1-10-war-to-tomcat7-or-tomcat8

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the grails.serverURL is used by grails to produce urls but not as a configuration to tell tomcat what application will resolve to a specific url.  That's handled by the config in tomcat itself.

Try this:

```
   http://yourdomain:port/GrailsApplication_1.0
```

And see if your application shows up